# How to Check the Checkbox present in the DataTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF. It may be simple, but I am struggling.

I created a `DataGrid` with one `DataGridTextColumn` and 7 `DataGridTemplateColumn`. All the 7 DataGridTemplateColumns have a `HeaderTemplate` and a `CellTemplate`. The `HeaderTemplate` has a `CheckBox` in its header. The DatagridCellTemplates are filled by images.

By default, the datagrid is filled with 'Yes' images. If the user click on the header checkbox, it has to fill the 'No' image to the cells of that column. And if the user unchecks, it has to go back to the 'Yes' image.

I created a ViewModel to fill the images for the cell.

Everything is working properly at first.

The issue is when I load back again (Edit feature), if the column is filled with 'No' image, then the corresponding column headers checkbox should be checked automatically for edit feature. And this is not happening.

I tried with creating a boolean variable in the viewmodel class and binding that variable to the checkbox which is also not working.
Please help.

### XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TimeTableGenie.Home.TimeOffPeriods"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TimeOff" Height="350" Width="550" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dgTimeOff" Margin="15,15,15,10" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding TimeOffDataRows, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" RowHeight="40" AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent">            

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Day" Binding="{Binding DayName}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Name="c1">
                            <CheckBox Name="chkbox1" IsChecked="{Binding CheckPeriod}" Content="1" Tag="1" Style="{StaticResource CheckForegroundColor}" Checked="chkbox_Checked" Unchecked="chkbox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>                            
                        </DataTemplate> 
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath1}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkbox2" IsChecked="{Binding CheckPeriod}" Content="2" Tag="2" Style="{StaticResource CheckForegroundColor}" Checked="chkbox_Checked" Unchecked="chkbox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath2}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkbox3" IsChecked="{Binding CheckPeriod}" Content="3" Tag="3" Style="{StaticResource CheckForegroundColor}" Checked="chkbox_Checked" Unchecked="chkbox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath3}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkbox4" Content="4" IsChecked="{Binding CheckPeriod}" Tag="4" Style="{StaticResource CheckForegroundColor}" Checked="chkbox_Checked" Unchecked="chkbox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath4}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkbox5" IsChecked="{Binding CheckPeriod}" Content="5" Tag="5" Style="{StaticResource CheckForegroundColor}" Checked="chkbox_Checked" Unchecked="chkbox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath5}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkbox6" IsChecked="{Binding CheckPeriod}" Content="6" Tag="6" Style="{StaticResource CheckForegroundColor}" Checked="chkbox_Checked" Unchecked="chkbox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath6}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkbox7" IsChecked="{Binding CheckPeriod}" Content="7" Tag="7" Style="{StaticResource CheckForegroundColor}" Checked="chkbox_Checked" Unchecked="chkbox_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath7}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Name="btnOk" Content="OK" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnOk_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Class:

```
class DataStore
{
    static DataStore objDataStore = null;
    public static DataStore GetInstance()
    {
        if (objDataStore == null)            
            objDataStore = new DataStore();
        return objDataStore;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TimeOffData> TimeOffDataRows = new ObservableCollection<TimeOffData>();
}

public class TimeOffData : ViewModelBase
{
    private String strDayName = String.Empty;
    private Uri ImageUrl1;
    private Uri ImageUrl2;
    private Uri ImageUrl3;
    private Uri ImageUrl4;
    private Uri ImageUrl5;
    private Uri ImageUrl6;
    private Uri ImageUrl7;        
    private bool bCheckPeriod = false; 

    public String DayName
    {
        get { return strDayName; }
        set { strDayName = value; }
    }

    public Uri ImagePath1
    {
        get { return ImageUrl1; }
        set { ImageUrl1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImagePath1"); }
    }

    public Uri ImagePath2
    {
        get { return ImageUrl2; }
        set { ImageUrl2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImagePath2"); }
    }

    public Uri ImagePath3
    {
        get { return ImageUrl3; }
        set { ImageUrl3 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImagePath3"); }
    }

    public Uri ImagePath4
    {
        get { return ImageUrl4; }
        set { ImageUrl4 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImagePath4"); }
    }

    public Uri ImagePath5
    {
        get { return ImageUrl5; }
        set { ImageUrl5 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImagePath5"); }
    }

    public Uri ImagePath6
    {
        get { return ImageUrl6; }
        set { ImageUrl6 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImagePath6"); }
    }

    public Uri ImagePath7
    {
        get { return ImageUrl7; }
        set { ImageUrl7 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImagePath7"); }
    }

    public bool CheckPeriod
    {
        get { return bCheckPeriod; }
        set { bCheckPeriod = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CheckPeriod"); }
    }
}
```

### backendcode:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace TimeTableGenie.Home
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for w2TimeOff.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TimeOffPeriods : Window
    {
        List<int> liPeriodNums = new List<int>();
        SubjectDetails objSubDetails;

        public TimeOffPeriods(SubjectDetails obj)
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            objSubDetails = obj;
            liPeriodNums.Clear();

            if(!objSubDetails.TimeOffPeriods.Equals(String.Empty))
            {
                // edit Timeoff
                // timeoff willbe only periodnumbers as comma separated (Ex: 3,5)
                // so put it into liPeriodNums list and call CreatePeriodRows() function.
                liPeriodNums = objSubDetails.TimeOffPeriods.Split(',').Select(sValue => Convert.ToInt32(sValue.Trim())).ToList();
            }
            CreatePeriodRows();            
        }


        void CreatePeriodRows()
        {
            DataStore objDataStore = DataStore.GetInstance();
            TimeOffData objTimeOffData = null;

            String[] strDays = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };

            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            String strImagePath;
            objDataStore.TimeOffDataRows.Clear();

            for (int iDayIter = 0; iDayIter < 5; iDayIter++)
            {
                objTimeOffData = new TimeOffData();
                objTimeOffData.DayName = strDays[iDayIter];

                for (int iPeriodIter = 1; iPeriodIter < 8; iPeriodIter++)
                {
                    if(liPeriodNums.Contains(iPeriodIter))
                    {
                        strImagePath = dirInfo.FullName + "pics\\no.png";
                        objTimeOffData.CheckPeriod = true;                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strImagePath = dirInfo.FullName + "pics\\yes.png";
                        objTimeOffData.CheckPeriod = false;
                    }

                    switch (iPeriodIter)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            objTimeOffData.ImagePath1 = new Uri(strImagePath);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            objTimeOffData.ImagePath2 = new Uri(strImagePath);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            objTimeOffData.ImagePath3 = new Uri(strImagePath);
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            objTimeOffData.ImagePath4 = new Uri(strImagePath);
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            objTimeOffData.ImagePath5 = new Uri(strImagePath);
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            objTimeOffData.ImagePath6 = new Uri(strImagePath);
                            break;

                        case 7:
                            objTimeOffData.ImagePath7 = new Uri(strImagePath);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                objDataStore.TimeOffDataRows.Add(objTimeOffData);
            }

            dgTimeOff.ItemsSource = null;
            dgTimeOff.ItemsSource = objDataStore.TimeOffDataRows;
            dgTimeOff.Items.Refresh();
        }

        private void chkbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
            int iPeriodNum = Convert.ToInt32(chkBox.Tag);
            liPeriodNums.Add(iPeriodNum);
            CreatePeriodRows();
        }

        private void chkbox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
            int iPeriodNum = Convert.ToInt32(chkBox.Tag);
            liPeriodNums.Remove(iPeriodNum);
            CreatePeriodRows();
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // get the checked tag values and put it into object. 
            // we have the tag values in the list, liPeriodNums            
            objSubDetails.TimeOffPeriods = String.Join(",", liPeriodNums);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No code, so I'll go on a whim here and say you didn't use `Mode=TwoWay` in your binding, even though from the top of my head I'm pretty sure it's two-way by default.

Comment: @Kilazur Unless it's devexpress, it's two way by default.

Comment: "I tried with creating a boolean variable in the viewmodel class and binded that variable to the checkbox which is also not happening." That's a description of what you hoped your code would do. It tells us nothing about the code you actually wrote to do it. Show us the code.

Comment: ok i will send the code.

Comment: Where is that habit of doing `itemscontrol.ItemsSource = null; itemscontrol.ItemsSource = something; itemscontrol.Items.Refresh();` coming from? I swear, i saw a question yesterday that did exactly the same weird thing...

Comment: With regard to your problem: Learn MVVM. It will help you developing a sane structure and logic for your program to achieve exactly what you want. Just some pointers (using MVVM terminology): Create a view model. Let this view model provide a collection (ObservableCollection) of TimeOffData object. Bind the datagrid itemssource to this collection. Have another boolean (or tri-state) property in the view model representing the checkbox. In the view model, track property changes of the TimeOffData objects in the collection. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Depending on the state of the TimeOffData objects, change the boolean property in the view model accordingly. Bind this boolean property to the checkbox. Also, the setter of this boolean property will have to adjust TimeOffData objects whenever the value of the boolean property changes (i.e., when the user toggles the checkbox)